# Getting error while starting the Cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am new to Cygwin.. Could you please help me, what is wrong here..

```
 Administrator@demosrv /cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/GCTI/lfm/utilities
    $ "C:/cygwin/cygrun.bat" bash "C:/cygwin/cygwin_setup.sh" administrator "superadmin"
    cygwin warning:
      MS-DOS style path detected: C:\cygwin\home\Administrator/.bashrc
      Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /home/Administrator/.bashrc
      CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
      Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
        http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames

    *** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/ssh_config file? (yes/no) yes
    *** Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file
    *** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/sshd_config file? (yes/no) yes
    *** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file
    *** Info: Privilege separation is set to yes by default since OpenSSH 3.3.
    *** Info: However, this requires a non-privileged account called 'sshd'.
    *** Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share/doc/openssh/README.privsep.
    *** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) yes
    *** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file

    *** Info: Sshd service is already installed.
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_config!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/sshd_config!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_key!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_key.pub!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /var/empty!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of /var/log/lastlog!
    *** Warning: Couldn't change owner of important files to Administrator
    Administrator!
    *** Warning: This may cause the sshd service to fail!  Please make sure that
    *** Warning: you have suufficient permissions to change the ownership of files
    *** Warning: and try to run the ssh-host-config script again.

    *** Warning: Host configuration exited with 14 errors or warnings!
    *** Warning: Make sure that all problems reported are fixed,
    *** Warning: then re-run ssh-host-config.
    System error 1069 has occurred.

    The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

For your information i used my windows username and password here..

Please let me know if you need any further details from me..

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Start, click Run, type gpedit.msc, and then click OK.
2. Expand Local Computer Policy, expand Computer Configuration, expand Windows
   Settings, expand Security Settings, expand Local policies, and then click User Rights Assignment.
3. Double-click Log on as a batch job, click Add user or group, type the name of the service account, and then click OK two times.
4. Double-click Log on as a service, click Add user or group, type the name of the service account, and then click OK two times.

Source : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb9cbc5c-b2f9-4656-97e9-f69542c0b10f/an-error-1069-the-service-did-not-start-due-to-logon-failure-occurred-while-performing-this?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: did it.. but unfortunately still i am facing the same issue

Comment: Look at this topic : http://www.kgx.net.nz/2010/03/cygwin-sshd-and-windows-7/, http://superuser.com/questions/485460/cygwin-sshd-did-not-start-due-to-a-logon-failure, hope it will help you...